# Rotate TextView DrawableRight OnClick

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, drawable

I have a TextView with an arrow set on the right of it. I want the arrow to rotate when it is clicked and return it back to the previous position when it is clicked again to show and hide text. I have been able to show and hide the information I just can't get the rotation animation to work.

**XML**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/expandable_first_next_last_air_date"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"                    
   android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_24dp"
   android:drawableTint="?attr/textColor"
   android:text="First, Next &amp; Last Air Date"
   android:textColor="?attr/textColor"
   android:textSize="26sp" />
```

**TextView OnClick Listener**

```
        tvExpandableFirstNextLastAirDate = findViewById(R.id.expandable_first_next_last_air_date);

        tvExpandableFirstNextLastAirDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (isTextViewClicked){
                tvFirstNextLastAirDate.setMaxLines(0);
                isTextViewClicked = false;
            }
            else{
                tvFirstNextLastAirDate.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                isTextViewClicked = true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java:

```
 final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    
    final TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
    final ImageView imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.image_view2);
    final AnimationSet animSetUp = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSetUp.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animSetUp.setFillAfter(true);
    animSetUp.setFillEnabled(true);

    final AnimationSet animSetDown = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSetDown.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animSetDown.setFillAfter(true);
    animSetDown.setFillEnabled(true);

    final RotateAnimation animRotateUp = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 180.0f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    animRotateUp.setDuration(1500);
    animRotateUp.setFillAfter(true);
    animSetUp.addAnimation(animRotateUp);

    final RotateAnimation animRotateDown = new RotateAnimation(180.0f, 0.0f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    animRotateDown.setDuration(1500);
    animRotateDown.setFillAfter(true);
    animSetDown.addAnimation(animRotateDown);

    final boolean[] isTextViewClickedForTextView1 = {true};
    final boolean[] isTextViewClickedForTextView2 = {true};
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isTextViewClickedForTextView1[0]) {
                textView.setMaxLines(0);
                isTextViewClickedForTextView1[0] = false;
                imageView.startAnimation(animSetUp);
            } else {
                imageView.startAnimation(animSetDown);
                textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                isTextViewClickedForTextView1[0] = true;

            }
        }
    });    
    
    textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isTextViewClickedForTextView2[0]) {
                textView2.setMaxLines(0);
                isTextViewClickedForTextView2[0] = false;
                imageView2.startAnimation(animSetUp);
            } else {
                imageView2.startAnimation(animSetDown);
                textView2.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                isTextViewClickedForTextView2[0] = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="text view 1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="text view 2"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_view2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

res/anim/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out. If I have multiple TextViews can I use the same boolean or will I have to make one for each TextView?

Comment: Would I also have to duplicate the image views for multiple text views?

Comment: I edited my answer.
But it's not standard at all.
May I ask what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I was wondering if when I show and hide the TextViews if I could reduce duplicate code as I am now using a switch case for the TextViews but the edit looks as I imagined. Thanks